# Split (explode) comma delimited column values to rows

Tags: mysql

**Description**

Following is Table Structure:

**eligibility_table**

```
ID     COURSE_ID     BRANCH_IDS
1      501           621,622,623
1      502
1      503           625
2      501           621
2      505           650
3      500
```

Now, I am making new table structure as describe below and inserting course_table,branch_table through eligibility_table. So following, final output I want

**course_table**

```
ID COURSE_ID
1  501
1  502
1  503
2  501
2  505
3  500
```

**branch_table**

```
ID BRANCH_ID
1  621
1  622
1  623
1  625
2  621
2  650
```

**Problem:**

I am struggling to write SQL QUERY for branch_table. I want to write a query like

```sql
INSERT INTO branch_table SELECT --- from eligibility_table --
```

Comment: what do you want to select from eligibility table. Is it the BRANCH_IDS that are not in the branch table.

Comment: AFAIK there is no mysql function that will split a string into multiple rows (some other databases can do it), and that's what you need here

Comment: [Mysql split column string into rows](http://www.marcogoncalves.com/2011/03/mysql-split-column-string-into-rows/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**UPDATED** You can do it with SQL like this

```
INSERT INTO branch_table (id, branch_id)
SELECT e.id, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(e.branch_ids, ',', n.n), ',', -1) branch_id
  FROM eligibility_table e CROSS JOIN 
(
   SELECT a.N + b.N * 10 + 1 n
     FROM 
    (SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) a
   ,(SELECT 0 AS N UNION ALL SELECT 1 UNION ALL SELECT 2 UNION ALL SELECT 3 UNION ALL SELECT 4 UNION ALL SELECT 5 UNION ALL SELECT 6 UNION ALL SELECT 7 UNION ALL SELECT 8 UNION ALL SELECT 9) b
    ORDER BY n
) n
 WHERE n.n <= 1 + (LENGTH(e.branch_ids) - LENGTH(REPLACE(e.branch_ids, ',', '')))
 ORDER BY id, branch_id
```

- The subquery with an alias of n generates on the fly a sequence of numbers (numbers or tally table) from 1 to 100 in this particular case using `UNION ALL` and `CROSS JOIN`. *Sometimes it's handy to have a real tally table in your db*.
- In outer select innermost [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) gets everything up to n'th element in a list and outer `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` extract right most part after a last delimiter effectively getting n-th element itself.
- `CROSS JOIN` allows us to produce a set of rows which is a cartesian product (of 100 rows in n and all rows in eligibility_table)
- condition in `WHERE` clause filters out all unnecessary rows from the resultset

*Note: this query will split up to 100 branch ids. If you need more or less you can adjust a limit by editing the inner subquery*

Result in branch_table:

```
| ID | BRANCH_ID |
------------------
|  1 |       621 |
|  1 |       622 |
|  1 |       623 |
|  1 |       625 |
|  2 |       621 |
|  2 |       650 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4f2a1/1)** demo

Answer (score 3):

If I'm correct in that you are changeing your database structure so it is actually normalized, and this is a one time thing, I'd suggest you do this in code. Connect to the database, read your old tables and insert the new. You can add some error-checking and exceptionhandling as well!

Just take your favorite language, and then do a standard `split()` on that comma-separated value, and insert those values in the table. If it doesn't work you can print out what line went wrong so you can manually fix those issues. (that will be much harder in sql to accomplish)

Comment: Yes, If there is no other way then I'll go with this way.