# Splitting SQL field at a Character

Tags: sql

Im after help with a split function I have a table of data in SQL with three columns as below

```
Part,Quantity,Designator

4010039,2,R60 R63

4010060,2,R13 R131

4010066,63,R3 R4 R5 R8 R9 R17 R32 R33 R34 R35 R39 R41 R42 R45 R49
```

It needs to be appended to an existing database table so the field 'Designator' needs to be split to form several rows when appended and the text needs to stay together so if, as in row 3 above, the 20th caracter is in the middle of text R32, I need it split before the R32 and keep the 'R32' text together and R32 would start row 2.  The Designators field can be up to 500 characters long and there is no set structure to it.

Results need to be like this

```
Part,Row,Designator

4010039,1,R60 R63

4010060,1,R13 R131

4010066,1,R3 R4 R5 R8 R9 R17 

4010066,2,R32 R33 R34 R35 R39 

4010066,3,R41 R42 R45 R49
```

Comment: I tried a few things the latest i found on

Comment: See this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17269444/split-explode-comma-delimited-column-values-to-rows